# Mysql affected_rows returns 1, but the actual mysql doesn't get updated

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function:

```
     public function update($id, $value)
    {
        $query = 'UPDATE ' . table .
                 ' SET ' . table . '.value = ?' .
                 ' WHERE ' . table . '.value = ?';

        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);

        if (!$stmt || !$stmt->bind_param('ii', $id, $value)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute() || !$stmt->affected_rows) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
}
```

The problem is that this function returns true, affected_rows returns 1, but this doesn't update my actual mysql table. If I'm trying to do the query inside the mysql, it works. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: Is you table name really table?

Comment: ```table``` should be ```$table```

Comment: Did you maybe forgot to change the order of $id, and $value. Because now there is standing UPDATE table SET table.value = $id WHERE table.value = $value. But the where clause is querying the record that needs to be updated.

Comment: And also, ```value``` is it your correct column name?  ```$this->connection->prepare($query)``` will always return ```false``` if you are using incorrect column name, and I suppose it is in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you maybe forgot to change the order of $id, and $value. Because now there is standing UPDATE table SET table.value = $id WHERE table.value = $value. But the where clause is querying the record that needs to be updated

Answer (score 1):

This is correct code.

```
public function update($id, $value)
{
    $query = 'UPDATE table SET value =? WHERE id =?';

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $value,$id);
    $status = $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt === false) 
    {
        trigger_error($this->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        return $stmt->affected_rows;
    }
}
```